# Reuseable configuration file for gulp

Tags: node.js, import, gulp

I want to ask a question about importing js file into another js file and use it in gulp. You can see my gulp.config file and gulpfile. when i try to run gulp task which is vet i am getting error like this ;

```
[00:06:21] Using gulpfile ~\pluralsight-gulp-master\gulpfile.js
[00:06:21] Starting 'vet'...
[00:06:21] 'vet' errored after 13 ms
[00:06:21] Error: Invalid glob argument: undefined
    at Gulp.src (C:\Users\Altan\pluralsight-gulp-master\node_modules\vinyl-fs\li
b\src\index.js:20:11)
```

gulp.config.js

```
module.exports = function(){
    var config = {
        //all js to vet
        alljs: [
            './src/**/*.js',
            './*.js'
        ]
    };

    return config;
};


gulpfile.js
var gulp = require ('gulp');
var jscs = require ('gulp-jscs');
var jshint = require ('gulp-jshint');
var util = require ('gulp-util');
var gulpprint = require ('gulp-print').default;
var gulpif = require ('gulp-if');
var args = require ('yargs').argv;
var config= require('./gulp.config');

gulp.task('vet',done=>{

    gulp
    .src(config.alljs)
    .pipe(gulpif(args.verbose,gulpprint()))
    .pipe(gulpprint())
    .pipe(jscs())
    .pipe(jshint())
    .pipe(jshint.reporter('jshint-stylish',{verbose:true}));

    done();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you are returning a function from `gulp.config.js`

when you require it, it should be

```
require('./gulp.config')()
```